# Restore database into another database as schema in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, database, schema, backup, restore

Can I restore database into another database as schema in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: No, not really - restoring a database always results in a new database on your server. You can then move the objects to another database's separate schema - but you cannot restore into an existing database into a new schema directly

Comment: @marc_s Do you have any idea as in how can i achieve merging 2 database into one with unique schema names?

Comment: Yes - just search the internet for the many discussions about "sql server merge databases".